# How to write multiple try/excepts efficiently

Tags: python

I quote often want to try to convert values to int and if they can't be converted, set them to some default value. For example:

```
try:
    a = int(a)
except:
    a = "Blank"
try:
    b = int(b)
except:
    b = "Blank"
try:
    c = int(c)
except:
    c = "Blank"
```

Can this be written more efficiently in Python rather than having to write out every try and except?

Comment: Why the downvote??

Comment: Why not have a function that does it, so you won't need to repeat yourself? You can even have this function to take multiple values.

Comment: I would put the three conversions into one single `try-except` clause, and use something like `except ValueError:`. It is not a good habit to use an `except` for avery exception.

Comment: @Alex Actually it is. The "best practice" is to have the minimum number of lines in every `try`. If they all were in the same `try`, how would you know which one of them failed?

Comment: Agree with DeepSpace - Also you want to avoid catching any errors that you aren't 100% sure you want to catch, so minimizing the number of lines of code in a try/except block ensures you only catch the errors on that minimal number of lines.

Comment: @DeepSpace: You are right, I misread the question a bit.

Comment: @Alex Though you are right that OP should use `except ValueError` instead of `except`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd simply use a function:

```
def int_with_default(i):
    try:
        return int(i)
    except ValueError:
        return "Blank"

a = int_with_default(a)
b = int_with_default(b)
c = int_with_default(c)
```

If necessary, you can always add a second argument that tells what the default value should be if you don't want to use "Blank" every time.